# FileVersionInfo behaves differently between a dll run from a WPF application and a command line application

Tags: c#, dll, fileversioninfo

I'm writing a dll which will be used in several environments, namely from our build machine. The program is responsible for getting a file's FileVersion. I'm using the following code within the .dll:

```
public string GetVersion(string filePath)
{
  FileVersionInfo temp = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(filePath);
  return temp.FileVersion;
}
```

Now when I run this function from the WPF test application I wrote everything works correctly; all values are filled out for the FileVersionInfo object.

However when I run this exact same function from within a Console Application project all the values in the FileVersionObject are null.

Anyone have any idea what's going on?

Comment: This question has some interesting suggestions, but it doesn't look like the issue was ever solved:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2221598/fileversioninfo-getversioninfo-incorrect-in-console-application

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out actually, the way I was retrieving the file path from the console was incorrect, I had a space character at the end of the directory name. I feel pretty dumb about it o.O

Comment: Which is odd, because File.Exists passed on this incorrect path, and the FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo didn't throw an error on it either.